# ionic cordova build ios --prod gets an JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building an app with IONIC 3 and I am having a problem with JS while I am building a production app.

I use the code `ionic cordova build ios --prod`
and the follow error appear

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[2769:0x104000000]   198493 ms: Mark-sweep 8037.6 (8188.4) -> 8037.6 (8189.4) MB, 10477.9 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.108, current mu = 0.001) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[2769:0x104000000]   211226 ms: Mark-sweep 8038.6 (8189.4) -> 8038.5 (8190.9) MB, 12720.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.048, current mu = 0.001) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0xc2936adc01d]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 0xc2936add3df]
Security context: 0x16d7fc81e681 <JSObject>
    2: write [0x16d90d9e6691] [/Users/guifeliper/My Apps/TalkABit2019/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:~9597] [pc=0xc2936afd123](this=0x16d90d9e6739 <Object map = 0x16d706426959>,s=0x16d7bd9bf491 <String[1]: V>)
    3: write(aka write) [0x16d90d9e7021] [/Users/guifeliper/My Apps/TalkABit2019/node_modules/typescrip...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x100039dbf node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x100039fc9 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x1001d1375 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x10059c572 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x10059f045 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x10059aeef v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x1005990c4 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x1005a594c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLigthRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x1005a59cf v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
[ERROR] Non-zero exit from subprocess.
```

I have added the --max_old_space_size=4096 on node, but sadly it just slows to the error shows up. What could I do?

**IONIC INFO**

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, ios 4.5.5
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 5 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.10.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node)
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : macOS
   Xcode  : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

**UPDATE**

I followed exactly this environment [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1426#issuecomment-407485178), but now the stops again on firebase. It just stop without say nothing.

```
> cordova build ios
Preparing Firebase on iOS
Building for iPhone X Simulator
Building project: /Users/guifeliper/My Apps/TalkABit2019/platforms/ios/talkaBit.xcworkspace
        Configuration: Debug
        Platform: emulator
Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/guifeliper/My Apps/TalkABit2019/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator12.1
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/guifeliper/My Apps/TalkABit2019/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Build settings from configuration file '/Users/guifeliper/My Apps/TalkABit2019/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h
```

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1036 << have you tried these?

Comment: @pmkro I have been trying most of this issues, but seems that the big problem is firebase. Trying to dig around that now.

Answer (score 11):

Node's max memory size can be increased:

In **terminal** console:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096
```

If using **Windows**:

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8096
```

Prior to running ionic build --prod

I faced the same issue and this resolved my problem. 
Credit: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16868